# jquery ajax in wordpress page not found error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

this link from ajax call
[ajax call from this page](http://www.mummycenter.com/baby-kick-counter/)

[output page](http://www.mummycenter.com/kick-ajax/)

```js
 $('#sw_stop,#cd_stop').live('click', function() {
          clicks += 1;
        if (clicks>=10) {
       clicks=10;
       var alt="Kick Count Completed!";
       $("#alert").show();
       document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML=alt;
       $.APP.stopTimer();
       var h=$("#sw_h").text();
       var m=$("#sw_m").text();
       var s=$("#sw_s").text();
       
       alert(s);
       //var name=$("#name").val();
            //var message=$("#message").val();
     
            $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"http://www.mummycenter.com/kick-ajax/",
            data:{hour:h,minute:m,second:s},
            success:function(data){
            $("#info").html(data);
            }
 
            });
 
      }
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
            
        });
```

above code for jquery ajax this code page not found error please help me.

Comment: Not sure, but i would say that live() method is deprecated: http://api.jquery.com/live/, you use newer jquery version, as i can see....

Comment: your spelling of mommy is this correct for you?sorry for asking :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for comment but problem is pre-defined keyword "hour","minute" that's why ajax not called but by renaming this pre-define keyword now work perfectly

```js
 $('#sw_stop,#cd_stop').live('click', function() {
          clicks += 1;
        if (clicks>=10) {
       clicks=10;
       var alt="Kick Count Completed!";
       $("#alert").show();
       document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML=alt;
       $.APP.stopTimer();
       var h=$("#sw_h").text();
       var m=$("#sw_m").text();
       var s=$("#sw_s").text();
       
       alert(s);
       //var name=$("#name").val();
            //var message=$("#message").val();
     
            $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"http://www.mummycenter.com/kick-ajax/",
            data:{ho:h,mi:m,se:s},
            success:function(data){
            $("#info").html(data);
            }
 
            });
 
      }
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
            
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're adding jquery library from external source, but wordpress by default adds jquery to the page. Loading it twice is not efficient, and might give conflicts, so either disable that in wordpress, or just don't add the external script source.

The jquery that comes with wordpress runs in no-conflict mode, meaning that you can't use the `$` shorthand. Instead you must use `jQuery`. You can use the $ in your code if you wrap it inside

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // your $ code here
});
```

`.live` is deprecated in v1.7 and removed in v1.9. Use `.on` instead.